# SQLAlchemy update PostgreSQL array using merge not work

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to access PostgreSQL database, and I defined the object like this:

```
class SessionLog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'session_log'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    recordFile = Column('record_file', String(128))
    appSrcPorts = Column('app_src_ports', ARRAY(Integer))
    info5 = Column('info5', String(100))
```

and I select and update the session_log table like this:

```
session = Session()
sessionLog = session.query(SessionLog).filter_by(id=sessionLogId).first()
sessionLog.appSrcPorts.append(1)
session.merge(sessionLog)
session.commit()
```

But it is weird the column 'app_src_ports' not update after I called merge() and commit().
And I find a ugly way to make it work, before the append() line, add this:

```
sessionLog.appSrcPorts = list(sessionLog.appSrcPorts)
```

Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: your solution (sessionLog.appSrcPorts = list(sessionLog.appSrcPorts) to make it a list worked as a charm :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the SQLAlchemy ORM relies upon detection of events in order to tell when some data has changed, and thus when data needs to be flushed.  in this case, you are altering the Python array value in-place, which does not by default produce any events.  In order for this to work you need to use the [mutable extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/mutable.html) in conjunction with the ARRAY type (as well as a `list` subclass which sends these events) in order for changes to be sent as events related to the parent `SessionLog` object.

Comment: Do you think it's a SQLAlchemy's bug?

Comment: well we should have a "MutableList" implementation ready to go in sqlalchemy.ext.mutable, which we don't right now (only MutableDict).  And, the ORM could introduce a system by which types can advertise their "mutable" version, thus decreasing the amount of boilerplate in order to use a Mutable type for standard cases like ARRAY. But these would both be enhancements, we don't call those bugs.

Answer (score 5):

Found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kirang89/22d111737af0fca251e3) which helped me a lot. I added a custom `__setitem__` to be able to change an item in the list, and `__delitem__` to delete one:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import Mutable
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

class MutableList(Mutable, list):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        list.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.changed()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        list.__delitem__(self, key)
        self.changed()

    def append(self, value):
        list.append(self, value)
        self.changed()

    def pop(self, index=0):
        value = list.pop(self, index)
        self.changed()
        return value

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, MutableList):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                return MutableList(value)
            return Mutable.coerce(key, value)
        else:
            return value
```

Then in your model:

```
your_field = db.Column(
    MutableList.as_mutable(ARRAY(db.String())),
    server_default="{}"
)
```

Comment: SQLA provides `MutableList` as an extension, no need for custom implementation (mostly, does not provide tracking of nested objects) anymore: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html#sqlalchemy.ext.mutable.MutableList